# REST: If the procedure is a DB UPDATE command, should your API call strictly be PUT?

Tags: rest, api-design

Consider the following invoice table with two entries, id 1 and 2:

```
id, item, date_paid
1, 'apple', ''
2, 'banana', ''
```

When a payment is made date_paid column needs to be updated.

What is a proper REST verb for this?

`POST invoices/1/payments`
or
`PUT invoices/1/payments`

I feel like POST is proper since I am "adding" a payment detail but then again internally I'm actually "updating" a DB row so PUT seems applicable also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your example, you have an invoice that was created in your Invoice table at some point in the past. You're now updating said invoice to reflect that a payment was made. That's definitely an update and PUT is the correct verb. Presumably you might also have a Payment table with the actual payment details (amount, payer, etc.). If so, then that's where you would be adding a new payment record. That call would be a POST.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Internally I don't have a payments table to keep it simple. Since you're suggesting PUT is correct in this case, what about if the user wants to edit the payment details (e.g., change date_paid due to clerical mistake)? I assume that is also PUT right, if yes then the verbs I use for adding and updating payment is both PUT.

Comment: Since both cases are modifying an existing record, then yes, a PUT is the correct verb in both instances.